# Next.js: instrumentation.ts does not run server-side

Tags: next.js

I need to run some code server-side on app launch to do some initialization in my next.js app. I discovered the [instrumentation feature](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/instrumentation) which seemed to cover my use case.

However, when I try to run code that access node.js libraries like `os`, I get an error:

```
 X ./instrumentation.ts:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'os'
> 1 | import os from 'os';
  2 | 
  3 | export async function register() {
  4 |   console.log('i am running server side. ' + os.hostname);
```

My instrumentation.ts looks like this:

```
import os from 'os';

export async function register() {
  console.log('i am running server side. ' + os.hostname);
}
```

Am I correct in saying that instrumentation.ts runs server-side so it should be able to access node.js libraries? If not, is there another way to run some initialization code on server launch?

I have a repro here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4t86qn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly right. It runs in all environment so you should wrap imports like this

```
export async function register() {
  if (process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME === 'nodejs') {
    const os = await import('os');
    console.log('i am running server side. ' + os.hostname);
  }
}
```

Comment: That fixes my stackblitz repo. However, I have a slightly different repo that still seems to fail: https://github.com/crummy/nextjs-instrumentation-error

Comment: The issue seems to occur only if I extract `process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME === 'nodejs'` to a conditional. If I put it in the `if` then it works fine. Baffling. Perhaps some kind of nextJS tree shaking thing.

Comment: I have asked a follow-up question in regards to the conditional behaviour. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427874/next-js-instrumentation-behaves-differently-with-conditional-extracted-to-variab