# Next.js instrumentation behaves differently with conditional extracted to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

This issue came from [an earlier issue I created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77314265/next-js-instrumentation-ts-does-not-run-server-side), which was resolved, but the underlying behaviour is so baffling I'm desparate to know what is going on.

Next.js has an [experimental feature called Instrumentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/instrumentation) that allows code to be run on boot-up. It seems to run both server-side and client-side, so a special check is necessary if nodejs-dependent imports are to be used. I have working code that uses this functionality:

```js
export async function register() {
  if (process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME === 'nodejs') {
    const os = await require('os');
    console.log(os.hostname());
  }
}
```

However, the following code does not work:

```js
export async function register() {
  const isServer = process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME === 'nodejs'
  if (isServer) {
    const os = await require('os');
    console.log(os.hostname());
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
- error ./instrumentation.ts:12:21
Module not found: Can't resolve 'os'
  10 |   const isServer = process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME === 'nodejs'
  11 |   if (isServer) {
> 12 |     const os = await require('os');
     |                     ^
  13 |     console.log(os.hostname());
  14 |   }
  15 | }
```

Obviously I can use the first one and be happy. But can anyone explain why the second fails? Perhaps something involving tree shaking, or caching, or...?

[Here's a Stackblitz repro.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-tzgbcc?description=The%20React%20framework%20for%20production&file=next.config.js,instrumentation.ts&title=Next.js%20Starter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design NextJS repalces any `process.env.*` references during build time. So i think the output of the first case will be something like this:

```js
if(false) {
 const os = require("os");
 // ....
}
```

And then it will be completely removed by the bundler/minifier itself.

---

You can see `loadEnvConfig()` [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/bd2d8a3b23391b587efd3aeca81e79efa0455381/packages/next-env/index.ts#L109) what is actually called by the runtime environment/during build.

And if you the [webpack config for next](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/bd2d8a3b23391b587efd3aeca81e79efa0455381/packages/next/src/build/webpack-config.ts#L1908), you can see they have the [usedExports](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationusedexports), what tells webpack to "yeash maan feel free to purge unused things out of my codebase during bundling".

And why the code you posted doesnt work?
So basically, it will be compiled to:

```js
const variable = false;
if(variable) {
 const r = require("os");
}
```

And at this moment webpack/babel/anything else cannot determine if the variable is used only in that statement.

So unfortunately what you can do is to create a function that returns the given variable from process env, and it might work (didnt test it, sorry), or use it as is.
I get your problem with the working solution, but as it seems it's because of one of the limitations of the usual FE landscape/bundling process.

edit:
and you see the error as coming form a `*.ts` file, because of map files

Comment: Thanks. All this tooling seems kind of crazy sometimes.